# Download pdf with filled data in acroform - PDFJS

Tags: javascript, pdf, ecmascript-6, pdf-generation, pdf.js

I am integrating PDF JS in my web application with enabled renderIntrectiveForm property. So I am able to edit the form input in PDF, I am able to fill inputs. But the problem is I am not able to download the PDF with filled data.

I searched as much as I can. And I tried so hard to achieve the functionality. I also tried to update annotation manually as in below code in download function. But still, it is downloading the original PDF.

```
var pdf = PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument;
var downloadManager = PDFViewerApplication.downloadManager;
pdf.loadingTask.then(function(data){
    data.getPage(1).then(function(page){
        page.getAnnotations().then(function(annotations){
            annotations[1].fieldValue= "New Text"
            pdf.getData().then(function(blobData){
                var blob = (0, PDFJS.createBlob)(blobData, 'application/pdf');
                downloadManager.download(blob, "a.pdf", "a.pdf");
            })
        })
    })
});
```

I know i can send json to server and then create a new pdf with json(as in https://www.smartformsondemand.org). But I want to do it with client side only.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a similar solution while working with annotations.
For my use-case the `saveDocument` method of the `pdfDocument`'s `_transport` object made the trick.

i. e. the call to `viewer.pdfDocument._transport.saveDocument()` gave me the promise to the desired pdf-version.

Maybe this works for forms also?